# Chat Architecture - php + mysql + different clients

Tags: java, php, mysql, client, chat

I'm designing a chat aplication where the data will be stored in an mysql database and will be manipulated by php scripts.

I want to have the possibility of developing severall diferent clients. What are the best options to expose the funcionality of the php scripts to clients?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're trying to makes this follow an MVC pattern, but what you describe isn't really an MVC pattern, and this doesn't work in this context. (Amongst other points, where would the link between M and V be?)

Answer (score 2):

(As I said in a comment above, this isn't an MVC pattern at all.)

Typically, what you're trying to achieve can be done by developing a web-service to expose certain features of your application running on your server (and storing data in your database). You would need to define message formats to be exchanged between your client and your service. This is typically based on JSON or XML syntax.

Just a few more points:

> -Data- To store the data, that is, the messages and user info, i selected mysql because that's what's available on apache.

MySQL isn't available on Apache (Httpd). Apache and MySQL have little to do with one another, besides the fact there are "LAMP" stacks that bundle them together. In principle, nothing prevents you from using another RDBMS (e.g. PostgreSQL, MS SQL, ...) or even NoSQL databases.

> -Controller- To access and manipulate data i've chosen php because that's what's available on apache.

Again, PHP is a popular choice to run on Apache Httpd, but PHP is far from the only choice (you can implement services in Python or Perl, for example).

> -View(Client)- It's possible to develop diferent clients, as long as they can interact with the php scripts that have access to the
>   database. For now, i'm using Java to build the client. It has the
>   advantage of being used either as an applet or as a standalone
>   aplication that can be downloaded.

It's 2013, Java applets are a technology of the past. (Standalone Java applications or server-side Java are different.)

> I'll have cron jobs to select the last messages from each of the chat
>   rooms. Theses messages will be writen on to a file. Each chatroom will
>   have its file. To read the messages, the client has to ask for the
>   corresponding file and present its content to the user. To send
>   messages to the chat rooms, the client has to call the php script
>   passing informations like the destination chatroom, user id and so
>   on.. Insertions will be heavy on the database but reads will be a bit
>   lighter.

This is a clear case of premature optimisation, or inadequate optimisation (cron jobs run at best every minute, not ideal for a chat room). A well designed database (e.g. with appropriate indexes) might not have problems handling chat room traffic. You might want to read a bit more about web services and databases before trying to dive into this sort of details.